# Why do I appear to be missing the OnClick panel in UI Button to be able to add an OnClick event?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have watched a few tutorials on adding `OnClick` events to buttons in UI panels and they all have a panel in the button section where you can add a scrip to the on click event.
However, in my panel all I have is an expandable list that shows `Persistent calls` with no option to add any script (image for reference)

My Panel, with no option to add a script to `OnClick` Events

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your Inspector is in **`Debug` mode** which exposes all fields without applying any property drawers and editor scripts!

See [Unity Manual - Inspector → Toggle Debug Mode (bottom section)](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InspectorOptions.html)

> **Toggling Debug Mode**
> Normally, the Inspector window is configured as an editor for the selection’s properties. But sometimes it’s useful to only see the properties and their values. When you activate Debug mode, the Inspector shows only the properties and their values. If the selection has script components, Debug mode also displays private variables, although you can’t edit their values
>
> You can toggle Debug mode for each Inspector window individually.
>
> - To turn on Debug mode, click the More Items <kbd>⋮</kbd> button to open the context menu, and select `Debug`.
> - **To return to Normal mode, click the More Items <kbd>⋮</kbd> button to open the context menu, and select `Normal`.**

In theory you could still add elements to the `Persistent Calls` list by editing the `size` value ... but really just switch back to normal mode ;)

Comment: Dear god I can't believe it was something that simple. Thank you! This fixed the issue